# datatable vueJS don´t show data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-8

I´m trayin integrate datatable in my component vue. For this i´m using this library:

```
https://jamesdordoy.github.io/
```

i´m install in my proyect, i has configured it, created my component and include in my view, but returned me this message:

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array
```

my component it´s:

```
<template>
    
    <div>

        <div class="row justify-content-center w-100">
            <data-table :data="data" :columns="columns" @on-table-props-changed="reloadTable"></data-table>
        </div>

        
    </div>

</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                url: "/admin/vue/getAllUsers",
                data: {},
                tableProps: {
                    search: '',
                    length: 10,
                    column: 'id',
                    dir: 'asc'
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        label: 'ID',
                        name: 'id',
                        orderable: true,
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Name',
                        name: 'name',
                        orderable: true,
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Email',
                        name: 'email',
                        orderable: true,
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.cargar(this.url);
        },
        methods:{
            cargar(url = this.url, options = this.tableProps){
                axios.get(url, { params: options })
                        .then((response) => {
                            this.data = response.data;
                        })
                        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
            },
            reloadTable(tableProps) {
                this.cargar(this.url, tableProps);
            
            }
                
        },
        
        
    }
</script>
```

i was trayed with `response.data[0]` the error disappear but my table it´s empty, i don´t know that i´m doing wrong.

In my controller i have this:

```
return User::all();
```

i´m working with laravel 8

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass props `:items = "data"` instead of `:data = "data"`